# Windows Folders with Special Character, how to handle them on a loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, character, special-characters, directory

I have this shared folder,

```
\\FILE48\BUGB-MONTR‚AL_RŠGLEMENTS_GESTIONNAIRES
```

After activating chcp 1252

```
\\FILE48\BUGB-MONTRéAL_RèGLEMENTS_GESTIONNAIRES
```

I want to create a script which should be able to read a file, which contains that folder and handle it. 
Currently I am not able to work on this,

for example I have a file :
file1.txt

```
\\FILE48\BUGB-MONTR‚AL_RŠGLEMENTS_GESTIONNAIRES
```

doing a for /f %%i in (file1.txt) do diruse %%i
doesn't work.

The output of my script attempts to reach \FILE48\bugb-Montrâ€šal_RÅ glements_Gestionnaires

not sure why.

Comment: That's utf-8 encoding.  Very hard to guess how that happened.  Maybe the editor you used to edit the script.

Comment: @HansPassant I obtained the list of shares through another script. so I am not sure how can I work around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using: 
iconv -f utf-8 -t Windows-1252 < input >output 
After this the text, strings started to work ok.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the property of the command windows and change the font to "Lucida Console".  Then change chcp to 1252.  This should get you the right characters.